# Test a map[string]interface{} with ginkgo and gomega

Tags: go, ginkgo, gomega

During testing I get the error message

```
Expected
        <[]map[string]interface {} | len:0, cap:0>: []
    to equal
        <[]map[string]interface {} | len:0, cap:0>: nil
```

How Do i declare a []map[string]interface {} to be "nil"?

thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Those 2 are different values of the same type. If what you care not equality, but the length - compare lengths.

Comment: I want them to be the same value of "nil"

Comment: They are different values, they cannot be "the same". The same way `1` and `0` are different values.

Comment: yeah, so How do I reassign the one that is equal to an array to be nil

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gomega matchers like this:

```
Describe("the test", func() {
    var obj []map[string]interface{}

    It("should be nil", func() {
        Expect(obj).To(BeNil())
    })

    It("should be empty []", func() {
        Expect(obj).To(BeEmpty())
    })
})
```

These tests will pass if the value is not initialized also.

This is how you can declare the `map[string]interface{}` to be nil:

```
var obj []map[string]interface{}
// OR
var obj []map[string]interface{} = nil
```